# Mocking exported const in react.js jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

I am testing a React Component in Jest using Mount. The component uses a const object from another ts file called utils.tsx

The component works fine when run separately but errors out when mounted using jest.
Any idea as to how to mock the const object?

```
//utils.tsx

export const params = {
   isEnabled: true,
   cluster_name: 'some cluster'
}

// React component cluster.tsx

import {params} from 'utils';

somefunc = () => {
   // works when running the application
   console.log(params.cluster_name);
}

// Test file

// This test throws - cannot access property cluster_name of undefined
describe('Should print cluster name', () => {
   mount(
     <Provider> 
         <Cluster/>
     </Provider>
   );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jest.mock('utils.tsx', () => ({
  params: {
    isEnabled: false,
    cluster_name: 'mock cluster'
  }
}));

describe('Should print cluster name', () => {
   mount(
     <Provider> 
         <Cluster/>
     </Provider>
   );
})
```